# PHP Telegram Bot: calling functions from another php file results in 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: php, bots, telegram

I am making a telegram bot using PHP. Currently, I have many functions in my bot.php file but I would like to put them in a separate file bot-functions.php. However, when I do so, my bot starts returning 500 Internal Server Errors.

Here's the code:

bot.php with all the functions:

```
<?php

include __DIR__ . './Filter.php';
include 'telegram-functions.php';

$update = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), TRUE);
$filter = new Filter();

/**
 * Sends message to user who sent the original message.
 * 
 * @param $message
 * @param $text
 */
function informUser($message, $text) {
  $userId = $message['from']['id'];
  sendMsg($userId, $text);
}

/**
* Sends a report to jail channel
* 
* @param $message
* @param $text
* @param $reason
*/
function sendToJail($message, $text, $reason) {
  $jailId = $message['chat']['id']; # edit $jailId to match jail channel id
  $username = $message['from']['username'];
  $report = "Message from @".$username." deleted.\nMessage: ".$text."\nReason: ".$reason;
  sendMsg($jailId, $report);
}

/**
* Handles message without net id
* 
* @param $chatId
* @param $message
* @param $text
*/
function handleNoId($chatId, $message, $text) {
  delMsg($chatId, $message['message_id']);
  sendToJail($message, $text, "Message has no net id.");
  informUser($message, "Your message has been deleted due to no net id. \nMessage sent: ".$text);
}

/**
* Handles message with profanity
* 
* @param $chatId
* @param $message
* @param $text
*/
function handleProfanity($chatId, $message, $text) {
  delMsg($chatId, $message['message_id']);
  sendToJail($message, $text, "Message has profanity.");
  informUser($message, "Your message has been deleted due to profanity(s). \nMessage sent: ".$text);
}

/**
 * Handles messages that have net id and no profanities
 * 
 * @param $chatId
 * @param $text
 * @param $filter
 */
function handleGoodMessage($chatId, $text, $filter) {
  $id = $filter->getId($text);
  $report = "Message '".$text."' passed the filters.\nID: ".$id;
  sendMsg($chatId, $report);
}

/**
 * Handles messages
 * 
 * @param $message
 * @param $filter
 */
function handleMessage($message, $filter) {
  $text = $message["text"]; # assigns $text to message sent
  $chatId= $message["chat"]["id"];
  if (!($filter->hasNetId($text)))  {
    handleNoId($chatId, $message, $text);
  } elseif ($filter->hasProfanity($text)) { # checks if message has $profanity
    # message contains profanity
    handleProfanity($chatId, $message, $text);
  } else {
    handleGoodMessage($chatId, $text, $filter);
  }
}

if (array_key_exists("message", $update)) { # checks if update is a new message
  # update is a new message
  handleMessage($update["message"], $filter);
} elseif (array_key_exists("edited_message", $update)) { # checks if update is an edited message
  # update is an edited message
  handleMessage($update["edited_message"], $filter);
}
```

bot.php without functions:

```
<?php

include __DIR__ . './Filter.php';
include 'telegram-functions.php';
include 'bot-functions.php';

$update = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), TRUE);
$filter = new Filter();

if (array_key_exists("message", $update)) { # checks if update is a new message
  # update is a new message
  handleMessage($update["message"], $filter);
} elseif (array_key_exists("edited_message", $update)) { # checks if update is an edited message
  # update is an edited message
  handleMessage($update["edited_message"], $filter);
}
```

bot-functions.php:

```
<?php

include __DIR__ . './Filter.php';
include 'telegram-functions.php';

/**
 * Sends message to user who sent the original message.
 * 
 * @param $message
 * @param $text
 */
function informUser($message, $text) {
  $userId = $message['from']['id'];
  sendMsg($userId, $text);
}

/**
* Sends a report to jail channel
* 
* @param $message
* @param $text
* @param $reason
*/
function sendToJail($message, $text, $reason) {
  $jailId = $message['chat']['id']; # edit $jailId to match jail channel id
  $username = $message['from']['username'];
  $report = "Message from @".$username." deleted.\nMessage: ".$text."\nReason: ".$reason;
  sendMsg($jailId, $report);
}

/**
* Handles message without net id
* 
* @param $chatId
* @param $message
* @param $text
*/
function handleNoId($chatId, $message, $text) {
  delMsg($chatId, $message['message_id']);
  sendToJail($message, $text, "Message has no net id.");
  informUser($message, "Your message has been deleted due to no net id. \nMessage sent: ".$text);
}

/**
* Handles message with profanity
* 
* @param $chatId
* @param $message
* @param $text
*/
function handleProfanity($chatId, $message, $text) {
  delMsg($chatId, $message['message_id']);
  sendToJail($message, $text, "Message has profanity.");
  informUser($message, "Your message has been deleted due to profanity(s). \nMessage sent: ".$text);
}

/**
 * Handles messages that have net id and no profanities
 * 
 * @param $chatId
 * @param $text
 * @param $filter
 */
function handleGoodMessage($chatId, $text, $filter) {
  $id = $filter->getId($text);
  $report = "Message '".$text."' passed the filters.\nID: ".$id;
  sendMsg($chatId, $report);
}

/**
 * Handles messages
 * 
 * @param $message
 * @param $filter
 */
function handleMessage($message, $filter) {
  $text = $message["text"]; # assigns $text to message sent
  $chatId= $message["chat"]["id"];
  if (!($filter->hasNetId($text)))  {
    handleNoId($chatId, $message, $text);
  } elseif ($filter->hasProfanity($text)) { # checks if message has $profanity
    # message contains profanity
    handleProfanity($chatId, $message, $text);
  } else {
    handleGoodMessage($chatId, $text, $filter);
  }
}
```

Comment: see your logs and you can show us the error

Comment: You re-include the same files (include __DIR__ . './Filter.php';
include 'telegram-functions.php';) include them only once in the main script

Comment: I deleted the repeated include lines and it worked. Thanks @Unbywyd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted the repeated include lines and it worked. Thanks @Unbywyd!

So now my bot-functions.php looks like this:

```
<?php

include __DIR__ . './Filter.php';
include 'telegram-functions.php';

/**
 * Sends message to user who sent the original message.
 * 
 * @param $message
 * @param $text
 */
function informUser($message, $text) {
  $userId = $message['from']['id'];
  sendMsg($userId, $text);
}

/**
* Sends a report to jail channel
* 
* @param $message
* @param $text
* @param $reason
*/
function sendToJail($message, $text, $reason) {
  $jailId = $message['chat']['id']; # edit $jailId to match jail channel id
  $username = $message['from']['username'];
  $report = "Message from @".$username." deleted.\nMessage: ".$text."\nReason: ".$reason;
  sendMsg($jailId, $report);
}

/**
* Handles message without net id
* 
* @param $chatId
* @param $message
* @param $text
*/
function handleNoId($chatId, $message, $text) {
  delMsg($chatId, $message['message_id']);
  sendToJail($message, $text, "Message has no net id.");
  informUser($message, "Your message has been deleted due to no net id. \nMessage sent: ".$text);
}

/**
* Handles message with profanity
* 
* @param $chatId
* @param $message
* @param $text
*/
function handleProfanity($chatId, $message, $text) {
  delMsg($chatId, $message['message_id']);
  sendToJail($message, $text, "Message has profanity.");
  informUser($message, "Your message has been deleted due to profanity(s). \nMessage sent: ".$text);
}

/**
 * Handles messages that have net id and no profanities
 * 
 * @param $chatId
 * @param $text
 * @param $filter
 */
function handleGoodMessage($chatId, $text, $filter) {
  $id = $filter->getId($text);
  $report = "Message '".$text."' passed the filters.\nID: ".$id;
  sendMsg($chatId, $report);
}

/**
 * Handles messages
 * 
 * @param $message
 * @param $filter
 */
function handleMessage($message, $filter) {
  $text = $message["text"]; # assigns $text to message sent
  $chatId= $message["chat"]["id"];
  if (!($filter->hasNetId($text)))  {
    handleNoId($chatId, $message, $text);
  } elseif ($filter->hasProfanity($text)) { # checks if message has $profanity
    # message contains profanity
```